# Client side Blazor HttpClient Factory

Tags: blazor

I am trying to add http client factory support to my client side blazor app and having hard time getting the http client factory to work.

So the questions are.

- Is the current build of blazor support having http client factory out
  of the box?
- If not is there a way it can be implemented ?

Thanks.

Comment: client-side uses a specially prepared HttpClient instance so the factory is not needed and not supported. How/why were you going to use it?

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer to this question ?

Comment: Yes i am still interested.

Comment: @enet can you share the solution if you have one please? 
it's a bit hard to unit test my code using the "httpclient "

Comment: @yasseros, the best solution is this: Create a WebAssembly Blazor App hosted with individual accounts. Then open the Program class definition file in the Client project...you'll see there how the HttpClientFactory is added to the DI container, and how it is configured to create named instances of the HtppClient service...